# How to unselect text in Word using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am writing in VBA to pick up data from an excel sheet and put it into a word document. Ideally these would be in three different lines. When I run it, it keeps the original text highlighted the entire time, so I end up with two blank lines, and the third line is correct. Is there a way I can assign the text to the first, second, and third lines always? Or is there a way I can deselect the text so when I add a paragraph, it adds a paragraph under the text instead of replacing it?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Sub Word()

Dim selectedJournalTab As String
Dim selectedDocumentNumber As String
Dim selectedHeader As String

selectedJournalTab = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Value
selectedDocumentNumber = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I6").Value
selectedHeader = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value

Dim wdapp As Word.Application
Set wdapp = New Word.Application
wdapp.Visible = True
wdapp.Activate

With wdapp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .Documents.Add
    
    .Selection.Text = selectedJournalTab
    .Selection.MoveDown
    .Selection.TypeParagraph
    
    .Selection.Text = selectedDocumentNumber
    .Selection.TypeParagraph
    .Selection.MoveDown
    
    .Selection.Text = selectedHeader
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed description of the process when running your code.
It can be beneficial to comprehend why the output differs from your expectations.

```
    ' insert the 1st paragraph which is selected
    .Selection.Text = selectedJournalTab
    ' There is only one paragraph in doc, `MoveDown` moves cursor to the end of line
    ' It is same as `.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd`
    .Selection.MoveDown
    .Selection.TypeParagraph 'Inserts a blank paragraph - succeed
    
    .Selection.Text = selectedDocumentNumber
    ' the 2nd paragraph is selected, `TypeParagraph` replaces selection with vbNewline and insert a blank paragraph
    .Selection.TypeParagraph
    ' Nothing change, cursor is at the start position of the 3rd paragraph
    .Selection.MoveDown
    
    ' insert the 3rd paragraph which is selected
    .Selection.Text = selectedHeader
```

---

There are several approaches to achieve the desired result.

```
With wdapp

    .Documents.Add
'    Option1: TypeText
    .Selection.TypeText Text:=selectedJournalTab & vbNewLine & _
        selectedDocumentNumber & vbNewLine & selectedHeader
        
'    Option2: TypeText and TypeParagraph
'    .Selection.TypeText Text:=selectedJournalTab
'    .Selection.TypeParagraph
'    .Selection.TypeText Text:=selectedDocumentNumber
'    .Selection.TypeParagraph 
'    .Selection.TypeText Text:=selectedHeader
    
'    Option3: If you prefer to use `Selection.Text`
'    Const wdCollapseEnd = 0
'    .Selection.Text = selectedJournalTab & vbNewLine & _
'        selectedDocumentNumber & vbNewLine & selectedHeader
'    .Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use TypeParagraph to move the cursor down. Here is updated code.

```
Sub Word()

Dim selectedJournalTab As String
Dim selectedDocumentNumber As String
Dim selectedHeader As String

selectedJournalTab = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Value
selectedDocumentNumber = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I6").Value
selectedHeader = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value

Dim wdapp As Word.Application
Set wdapp = New Word.Application
wdapp.Visible = True
wdapp.Activate

With wdapp
    .Documents.Add

    .Selection.TypeText Text:=selectedJournalTab
    .Selection.TypeParagraph
    .Selection.TypeText Text:=selectedDocumentNumber
    .Selection.TypeParagraph

    .Selection.TypeText Text:=selectedHeader
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to avoid the use of `Selection` and use the `Range` object instead.

```
Sub Word()

    Dim selectedJournalTab As String
    Dim selectedDocumentNumber As String
    Dim selectedHeader As String

    selectedJournalTab = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Value
    selectedDocumentNumber = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I6").Value
    selectedHeader = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value

    Dim wdapp As Word.Application
    Set wdapp = New Word.Application
    wdapp.Visible = True
    wdapp.Activate
    With wdapp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
        Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
    End With
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = selectedJournalTab & vbCr & selectedDocumentNumber & vbCr & selectedHeader
End Sub
```